# Mac - running python with sudo makes it get wrong libraries

Tags: python, macos, sudo, six

I'm trying to install pycuda on my mac machine.
Problem is, when I run python with sudo, it gets the wrong version for python-six, which is required by pycuda.
How can I fix this?

```
Jean-Lucs-MacBook-Pro:test Jean$ sudo python
Password:
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution("six").version
'1.4.1'
>>> import six
>>> print six.__file__
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.pyc
>>>


Jean-Lucs-MacBook-Pro:test Jean$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution("six").version
'1.9.0'
>>> import six
>>> print six.__file__
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.pyc
>>>
```

Comment: Type `which python` as your normal user and see which one you are running. Change the PATH environment variable for root so root runs the same one as you.

Comment: It's the same python

Comment: You need to put `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` first in the root path

Comment: what does  `import sys;sys.path` output for both?

Comment: for `sudo python` syspath returns a smaller string

Comment: add both paths exactly as they are

Comment: also you can try to verify it works  `sys.path.insert(1,"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/")` in your sudo python shell then try importing

Comment: `sys.path.insert` didn't work. The problem is that my sudo PATH uses the old apple frameworks path. I would have to remove it from the root path

Comment: I have the same problem (with effect like here https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-77). But `sys.path.insert` didn't help me too although `sudo python -c "import six; print six.__version__"` returns `1.9.0`..

Comment: I resolved my issue with the workaround provided in the Description of https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-77 but I would still like to know what is happening.

Comment: I managed to make a workaround by making a `.bash_profile` for root with the correct paths and changing the root login terminal to bash, so I can do all my work with `su -`. I would still appreciate a permanent fix.

Comment: `sudo -E`,  which theoretically should maintain the user environment, didn't work as well.